# Creating JDialog with GUI swing JFrame as its parent?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

This might be a very stupid question, but I just don't know how to do it.

I use swing GUI to create my JFrame. So it is `public class client extends javax.swing.JFrame`.

In the main method I am doing:

```
public void run() {
    new Client().setVisible(true);
}
```

When a button is clicked I want to do this:

```
JDialog d = new JDialog(frame, "Example", true);
```

Except I have no idea what goes into 'frame'. I tried to say Client, but that didn't work. What is suppose to go there so that my parent of JDialog is the frame where I am calling it from?

Comment: If the "this" variable at the point where you define JDialog d refers to your JFrame, then "this" is what you should substitute the _frame_ variable with. The JFrame is the **owner** of your JDialog d and not its parent. Use the word "parent" only for its super class.

Answer (score 1):

> When a button is clicked I want to do this:

You must have added an `ActionListener` to the button. The `ActionEvent` will contain the source object that you clicked.

So you can write generic code in the `ActionListener` to get the parent Window of the button:

```
JButton button = (JButton)event.getSource();
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( button );
JDialog d = new JDialog(window, "Example", true);
```